# Organizar jQuery Ruby On Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

tenho um app em rails 4 e após fazer o scaffolding ele gera um *.js.coffee para cada modelo, como ainda não estou usando coffeescript renomeei para *.js e estou tentando usar jQuery. O problema é que preciso disparar um processo demorado por ajax após o carregamento da pagina `itens/show/x` e fiz da seguinte maneira

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({ 
    url:'/get_content_recommendation/' + gon.item_id + '.js',
    type:"get"
  });
});
```

O problema é que ele está executando em todas as paginas do app, por causa do `<%= javascript_include_tag "application", media: "all" %>` no layout antes do `<%= yield %>`

Qual a melhor solução para separar o jQuery por view, existe alguma gem ou alguma boa pratica?  Essa é a melhor maneira de disparar processo por ajax após o carregamento da pagina?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Rails recomenda o uso de [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript), em que se usa seletores para manipular os elementos:

```
$("#id")
$(".classe")
$("table[data-table]")
// etc
```

Assim, **uma das** maneiras possíveis é você se basear num elemento específico daquela página:

```html
<div id="div-especifica-desta-pagina">
  ...
</div>
```

E então, via jQuery:

```
$div_especifica = $("#div-especifica-desta-pagina");
if ($div_especifica.lenght) {

  $.ajax({ ... });

}
```

O código dentro do `if` só será executado se o elemento for encontrado.

---

Uma alternativa seria criar uma função Javascript no formato `NomeDoControlador-NomeDaAção`:

```
function UsuariosIndex() {

  $.ajax({ ... });

}
```

E então chamá-la via uma tag `<script>` apenas na página correta:

```html
<script>UsuariosIndex()</script>
```

Comment: Que legal! Desse jeito é possível usar separar o javascript dentro de cada .js e manter a view livre de javascript. Devo ter `$(document).ready(function() {...});` para cada comando, apenas 1 por arquivo ou ele não é necessário?

Comment: @Awkward Se você estiver chamando a tag script no <head> (necessario com turbolinks), terá que usar sim, não faz mal chamar várias vezes. Se chamar no final da pagina antes do <body> aí não precisa.

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa é que eu uso é definir um bloco no layout para injetar arquivos específicos de js, que só serão utilizados naquela view, você pode utilizar assim:

```
<% content_for :footer do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'itens_load' %>  
<% end %>
```

Basta que no seu layout tenha um bloco `<%= yield :footer %>` assim você pode incluir o js especifico no bloco. E vale lembrar que você deve adicionar o seus assets específicos ao precompile do seu arquivo `config/production.rb`, no exemplo seria: `config.assets.precompile += %w( itens_load.js )`